# Insert comma separated values with some constant value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have one comma separated strings like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" and I want to insert this values in a table column with other values are constant like

```
Insert into tbl(value1, value2, value3) values(@v1, @v2, 1)
Insert into tbl(value1, value2, value3) values(@v1, @v2, 2)
Insert into tbl(value1, value2, value3) values(@v1, @v2, 3) etc.
```

Where @v1,@v2 values are always constant.

So how should I write the query?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you using to insert data into SQL Server (i.e. what language?)

Comment: I am using SSMS for creating query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
create table tbl (value1 int, value2 int, value3 int);
declare @v1 int = 0;
declare @v2 int = -1;
declare @var varchar(8000) = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7';

insert into tbl 
  select @v1, @v2, s.Item
  from delimitedsplit8K(@var, ',') s

select * from tbl;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GBVJS38200

returns:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 | value3 |
+--------+--------+--------+
|      0 |     -1 |      1 |
|      0 |     -1 |      2 |
|      0 |     -1 |      3 |
|      0 |     -1 |      4 |
|      0 |     -1 |      5 |
|      0 |     -1 |      6 |
|      0 |     -1 |      7 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

Answer (score 1):

In case you need an in-line version

**Example**

```
Declare @v1 varchar(25) = 'SomeValue'
Declare @v2 varchar(25) = 'OtherValue'
Declare @S  varchar(max)= '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'

Insert Into tbl (value1, value2, value3)
Select @v1,@v2,RetVal
 From (
        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
      ) A
```

**The Row Inserted Look Like This**

[image]